# Show that M is a basis in P2. Which polynomial has the coordinates 1,1,1 in the base?

Tags: linear-algebra

$M= \{ 1-x, 1 + x + x^2, 1 - x^2 \}$ , so I take it I should prove that they are linearly independent but when I do that I get that $x$ could be $0$ or $1$, which means that they are linearly dependent.
Am I just wrong in my execution?

Comment: that 1-1 shall be a typo…a set that contains zero must be linearly dependent. May I ask what is the definition of linearly dependent?

Comment: in the case of polynomial you can't take x to be a number since you are talking about equality of functions…f(x)=x does not equal g(x)=x^2 since their function value are different for some x (say x =2

Comment: two functions are equal iff f(x)=g(x) for all x…is suffices to say they are not the same if their function value are different at some x but f(0)=g(0) doesn't mean f=g…

Comment: in case of function…the zero you are talking about is the zero function…that is the function h(x)=0 for all x

Comment: @LiChunMin yeah the 1-1 was a typo

Comment: so I urge to show that $1, x, x^2$ is a basis for P2 then use your usual technique for n-tuple of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "polynomial that has coordinates 1, 1, 1 in the base" is, by definition of "coordinates" and "base", 1(1- x)+ 1(1+ x+ x^2)+ 1(1- x^2).  Do that multiplication.

But to show that 1- x, 1+ x+ x^2, and 1- x^2 are "linearly independent" you need to show that for **any** a, b, c there exist numbers, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha(1- x)+ \beta(1+ x+ x^2)+ \gamma(1- x^2)= ax^2+ bx+ c$.
Do the multiplications on the left to get $\alpha- \alpha x+ \beta+ \beta x+ \beta x^2+ \gamma- \gamma x^2= (\alpha+ \beta+ \gamma)+ (-\alpha+ \beta)x+ (\beta- \gamma)x^2= c+ bx+ ax^2$.  In order that this be true for all x, we must have $\alpha+ \beta+ \gamma= c$, $-\alpha+ \beta= b$, and $\beta- \gamma= a$.  Those are three equations to solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$.  The three functions are independent if and only if it is possible to solve those equations.

Comment: Yeah I figured that's how to find out the coordinates. So since there are 6 variables but only 3 equations it shows that it can't be solved and that they are independent?

Comment: no…for fixed a, b, c you solve for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$

Comment: If that cannot be solved, then the given set of vector does not span $\Bbb{P}_2$! The logic in user247327's proof is that given any polynomial $\in \Bbb{P}_2$, it IS a UNIQUE set of coordinates to represent the polynomial.